# File download from server (not downloading?)

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I am currently working on a client that requires a button that will check a directory to see if a specific folder exists within it, if not it will then download a .zip file from my web server and once completed downloading, extract said .zip file to a directory.

For some reason the application returns that it is complete, however it does not download anything at all. I used a tutorial I found online to do this (http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/2013/06/how-to-make-downloader-in-c.html) with some modifications.

**Here is my download code:**

The Download Button:

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(HardCorpsPath))
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Downloading HardCorps Mod Pack (Full)", "Downloading", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            zipFileName = "HardCorps";

            HCDownloadURL = String.Format("http://www.survivaloperations.net/client/hardcorps/{0}.zip", zipFileName);

            WebClient Download_Client = new WebClient();//Declaring the webclient as Download_Client
            Download_Client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);//the event handler
            Download_Client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);// " "
            Download_Client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(HCDownloadURL.Trim().ToString()), Arma2OAPath);// " "

            //extract zip
            HCZipPath = Path.Combine(Arma2OAPath, @"HardCorps.zip");

            using (var zipFile = ZipFile.Read(HCZipPath))
            {
                zipFile.ExtractAll(Arma2OAPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
            }


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Directory Validated!");
            //Read users HardCorpsPath\version.txt and compare to server version.txt
            //if server version > user version, download patch.zip where "patch" == the number version of the server's version.txt (ex: 1001.zip)
            //On download complete, extract to HardCorpsPath and overwrite silently
        }
    }//close Download Button
```

The Rest:

```
private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbDownloader.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;//setting the progressbar value as downloadprogress
    }
    private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Downloading Successful ", "Download_Completed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);//just a messagebox          
        pbDownloader.Value = (0);//resetting the progressbar
    }
```

I am getting no errors until the application attempts to unzip a file that does not exist.

Pretty lost and confused, could use a set of fresh eyes to spot the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is likely that you're passing a file path in to `DownloadFileAsync` when you should be passing in a file name.

```
string fullFileName = Arma2OAPath + "test.zip";
Download_Client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(HCDownloadURL.Trim().ToString()), fullFileName );
```

Another issue is that 
[DownloadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is non-blocking. Which means that you immediately start unzipping the file without waiting for it to download. You should move the unzipping to `Completed()`.

Comment: I have moved the unzipping to the Completed() method and put it above the message (so it extracts before telling the user the download is complete) however now I get an exception "Cannot read that as a zip file" using DotNetZip 1.9 but it still extracts the zip file properly (just throws an exception as it does it). Here is the exception http://pastebin.com/NTrtMgR9